# Return class member without copy vs return local object in different implementations of abstract base class

Tags: c++, oop

Suppose the following setup where I have some abstract base class that defines a method `GetData` returning, e.g., a `std::vector` and two derived classes, one which holds the data in exactly that the same format as returned by `GetData` (`ProperSomeClass` below) and one that internally holds data in some weird legacy C format, i.e., has to convert that format into an `std::vector` in `GetData` (`DerivedSomeClass` below).

```
class ISomeClass
{
  virtual std::vector<int> GetData() const = 0;
};

class ProperSomeClass : public ISomeClass
{
private:
  std::vector<int> _data;
public:
  std::vector<int> GetData() const { return _data;  }
};

class DerivedSomeClass : public ISomeClass
{
private:
  const void* _legacyFormat;
public:
  std::vector<int> GetData() const
  {
    std::vector<int> temporary;
    // some code that extracts relevant data from legacy format
    return temporary;
  }
};
```

I'm looking for a nicer way to define (the return value of) `GetData` such that `ProperSomeClass` does not have to copy its `_data` member.

I cannot return a const reference because `DerivedSomeClass::GetData` would then return a reference to a deleted local object.

When returning a (smart) pointer I have to consider that `DerivedSomeClass::GetData` needs to allocate memory which has to be freed by the caller whereas the memory pointed to by the pointer returned by `ProperSomeClass::GetData` must not be freed by the caller and I wouldn't know how to solve this (except for using `shared_ptr` of which `ProperSomeClass` would need hold a copy it would never use just so that its data doesn't get deleted, which seems quite ugly to me).

In short, ideally I "just" want

- `ProperSomeClass::GetData` to give me a const reference without copying the data
- `DerivedSomeClass::GetData` to construct the vector and return it
- a general API for that in my base class

Is there a way to achieve this? Or what would be an alternative/better way to go about this all?

Comment: How about putting `_data` in the base class and just fill that up in both cases? This way you can return your const reference.

Comment: Weird that I thought about this just today. Have you considered `shared_ptr`? That assumes you can store your "owned" data in a `shared_ptr` yourself, but it would handle the "how does the caller know whether to delete" -> reference counter.

Comment: Have you considered constructing a `ProperSomeClass` from legacy data instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key here is that you want to return something from an interface that, depending on the concrete implementation, either needs to be destroyed by the caller (returned a copy/unique ownership) or not (returned a reference to member). The caller obviously cannot know this at compile time, so we need a mechanism that predicates the destruction of an object that way. You could write this yourself to be more explicit in your intent, but I think that `std::shared_ptr` will do the trick:

```
#include <vector>
#include <memory>

using VectorPtr = std::shared_ptr<std::vector<int>>;

class ISomeClass
{
  virtual VectorPtr GetData() const = 0;
};

class ProperSomeClass : public ISomeClass
{
private:
  VectorPtr _data;
public:
  VectorPtr GetData() const { return _data;  }
};

class DerivedSomeClass : public ISomeClass
{
private:
  const void* _legacyFormat;
public:
  VectorPtr GetData() const
  {
    VectorPtr temporary;
    // some code that extracts relevant data from legacy format
    return temporary;
  }
};
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Yes, I've thought about `shared_ptr` briefly as I pointed out in my post. I guess in the end it's probably the achieve this in my current setup. What I don't really like about it is that there is no reason for having `ProperSomeClass` deal with a pointer internally except for this return issue but I can't currently think of another way (hence my question)

Comment: There are other cases where you have to introduce pointers for some other reason. For example, a polymorphic class member.

Comment: Well, for polymorphic class members I could also make use of references, but I get the point. I'll mark this as solution since it most directly solves my question but have  ([Nelfeal's reply](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53159895/10609136)) as a close runner up for pointing out possibilities of avoiding the problem in the first place (if possible)

Answer (score 0):

You could add an `std::vector` to your `DerivedSomeClass` that you initialize in the ctor, and return as a const ref in your `GetData`, i.e.:

```
class DerivedSomeClass : public ISomeClass
{
public:
    DerivedSomeClass(void* legacyFormat):
    _legacyFormat(legacyFormat),
    _data(makeVectorFromLegacy(_legacyFormat))
    {}
private:
    const void* _legacyFormat;
    const std::vector<int> _data;
public:
    const std::vector<int>& GetData() const
    {
        return _data;
    }  
};
```

with a helper function to create that vector from the `const void*` pointer, the way you would extract the data in `DerivedSomeClass::GetData()`, except it'd be done only once.

This duplicates slightly with `ProperSomeClass`, which  may or may not be fine with you, although it has the advantage that it doesn't force the `std::vector` member variable on each derived classes, accounting for potential future implementation that might not need or want that member `std::vector`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It duplicates a bit with the one from @Nelfeal down below so I'd like to refer to my comments to that instead of copying those here.

Answer (score 0):

A defining property of `ISomeClass` is that it makes a `std::vector<int>` available. Since `ProperSomeClass` and `DerivedSomeClass` are both derived from `ISomeClass`, they both have to make this vector available in the same way. For example, if you want that way to be through a const reference, which seems very reasonable to me, then you need the vector to be a member of both classes.

Consider having a member `std::vector<int>` in `DerivedSomeClass`. If you want to avoid storing the same data twice (in the vector and the "legacy format" pointer), you probably could "extract the relevant data" in the constructor instead of `DerivedSomeClass::GetData` and get rid of the `_legacyFormat` member.

If `DerivedSomeClass` absolutely needs to keep `_legacyFormat`, I would figure this class and `ProperSomeClass` should be kept separate.

Comment: Thanks for the input! In general this might be an option, but unfortunately I cannot get rid of the `_legacyFormat`. In fact, the whole point of my `DerivedSomeClass` is to wrap around C code dealing with that format and provide a nicer interface. `ProperSomeClass` implements the same functionality but using nicer data structures. I'd like to keep both so that I can compare results. 

Having an additional `vector` in `DerivedSomeClass` would thus indeed mean that I have the same data twice, which I'd like to avoid for obvious reasons.

Comment: In addition to providing a reference for comparison of `ProperSomeClass`, `DerivedSomeClass::GetData` is useful for converting the old format into a `std::vector` and then using that as potential input for the constructor of `ProperSomeClass`

Comment: What does the old format contain exactly? An array of integers? If you can easily convert between it and a `std::vector<int>`, then another solution might be appropriate. If not, I personally would go for a return by value, because you duplicate data in `DerivedSomeClass::GetData` anyway, so let `ProperSomeClass::GetData` do the same.